# Flutter. How to update text inside GridView which inside PageView?

Tags: ios, flutter

I have a Page that contains a PageView and this PageView contains a GridView, and this GridView contains Text. Right now I want to update only one Text, not all the Text, how should I do without reloading all the PageView? For example, right now I only have a Text(), I want to make a widget out of this. How should I do that so I can update the specific Text and not reload all PageView and its children?

```
PageView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
  return GridView.builder(gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2, ), itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Text('$index');
  });
}, itemCount: 3,),
```

)

Answer (score 0):

My answer for you: `unnecessary`. Because GridView.builder cache your widget. You can change your text comfortably and setState in current Page. GridView will build the widgets have changed.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you get your updated data.

You can customize the GridView Item with a customized Widget, and call setState in that widget.

But you need a way to know when the data been updated.

```dart
class YourGridViewCell extends StatefulWidget {
  final String label;
  const YourGridViewCell({this.label});
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _YourGridViewCellState();
}

class _YourGridViewCellState extends State<YourGridViewCell> {
  String _label;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _label = widget.label;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(widget.label);
  }

  // you can call this to update cell.
  void _updateText(String newLabel) {
    setState(() {
      _label = newLabel;
    });
  }
}
```